# Unable to Cover 100% test class due to return null

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

below is my code

```
Public Class Testmanage{
    public Testmanage(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    }
    public pageReference load()
    {
        if(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')!= '' || ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id') != null)
        {
             Id id = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
             List<Test__c>lstTest= [Select Phone__c from Test__c where id=:id LIMIT 1] ;
             if(!lstTest.isEmpty())
             {
                 PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/apex/OppoAgr?id='+lstTest[0].Phone__c);
                 pageRef.setRedirect(true);
                 return pageRef;
             }
             return null;          
        }    
        return null;
    }
}
```

Below is my test class

```
@istest
public class Test_Data1 {static testmethod void Testmeth1(){ 
    Test__c tst=new Test__c(name='test',phone__C='3223233');
    insert tst;

    ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.standardController(tst);
    Testmanage cs=new Testmanage(sc);
    pagereference pr = page.Demopage;
    test.setCurrentPage(pr);
    ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('id',tst.id);
    cs.loadAction();
}
static testmethod void Testmeth1(){
    Test__c tst=new Test__c(name='test',phone__C='3223233');
   // insert tst;
            ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.standardController(tst);
    Testmanage cs=new Testmanage(sc);
    pagereference pr = page.Demopage;
    test.setCurrentPage(pr);
    ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('id',null);
    cs.load();

}
```

I am not able to cover last return null statement

Comment: Why do you think that is? Any thoughts on how you could prevent that, or if it even matters?

Comment: Do you have a compelling reason to cover that last line for 100%? I'd say your first/redundant `return null` is the culprit though

Comment: As i am new to coding ,i dont understand how to cover this.Please suggest

Answer (score 1):

If the aim is to test (and also cover) the body of the method, in your test you will need to insert a `Test__c` object and add its Id value to the page parameters so the body of the method is executed:

```
Test__c t = new Test(Phone__c = '123 456 789');
insert t;
ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('id', t.Id);

Testmanage c = ...;
PageReference pr = c.load();
```

In the method itself, take care to escape the phone string value as it may contain spaces. A simple way of doing that is to not build the URL yourself but leverage the `PageReference` class that has correct escaping built in:

```
PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/apex/OppoAgr');
pageRef. getParameters().put('id', lstTest[0].Phone__c);
```

**PS**

With more code posted in the question, it looks like this is a controller extension for `Test__c` and in that case it is better to get the Id value from the standard controller:

```
public Class Testmanag {

    private ApexPages.StandardController sc;

    public Testmanage(ApexPages.StandardController sc) {
        this.sc = sc;
    }

    public PageReference load() {
        if (s.getId() != null) {
            PageReference pr = Page.OppoAgr;
            Test__c t = [select Phone__c from Test__c where Id = :sc.getId()];
            pr.getParameters().put('id', t.Phone__c != null ? t.Phone__c : '');
            return pr;      
        }    
        return null;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately to get tests to pass it is still necessary to run a query rather than use the standard controller reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly call the load() method without setting the `ApexPages.currentPage` parameter so that it will directly return the null value and in your normal `testmethod` cover the code with setting the parameter.